# how can I play and stream video file over udp in single application

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

I need an application which opens a video file, displays on screen and streams over udp to network for other clients.

Is it possible

Comment: Most things are possible. What are you really asking? For info on how to start writing your own such application, or for someone to recommend an already existing one? The latter is off-topic, and for the former, there's too little info here to start from.

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the offical OBS site, it‘s possible to stream a UDP with OBS and from my oppinion the easiest way. 
And if you have questions, the OBS community